# Laravel 4 Pagination Buttons Not Working (Querying entire DB)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination

I'll start by saying i've already consulted the Laravel 4 documentation on Pagination and tried many methods to get this to work.

I am using Eloquent together with Laravel 4's Pagination class.

**Problem:** In my results page, i'm trying to paginate my results for what we'll call "trucks" DB. It works fine and I get exactly what I want at first (a limit of five results). Problem is when I click one of the page numbers (which don't appear to be accurate) created by pagination, the whole DB is queried and it takes me to the wrong page. I'm using where clauses and three dropdowns to limit the searcher's results but the pagination screws all that up. Here's a look at my controller logic:

```
$results = $query->Paginate(5);
    return View::make('results')->with('trucks', $results);
```

**Blade Template**

```
@if ($trucks) 
    @foreach ($trucks as $truck)
```

{{ $trucks->link() }}

How can I make sure that the page numbers work correctly and don't query the entire DB? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have to use the `appends()` method.

`$trucks->appends(array('sort' => 'votes'))->links()`

This will only work for laravel 4 which I suppose you are using.

More info about the `appends` method [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but not sure I understand the problem still. Yup i'm using Laravel 4. But what are the two parameters in the appends array and how should this fix the problem? In other words what is the purpose of appends? I'm glad you suggested it because I was looking into it but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks @akad0 you sent me in the right direction. I had to add this {{ $trucks->appends(Input::query())->links() }} and now it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I could not comment earlier. Glad you solved it